# Can I use properties-reader npm package in an angular application

Tags: angular

I am trying to use properties-reader NPM package in angular application. But I am getting error- Module not found: Error Can't Resolve 'path'/'fs'...
So can properties-reader be used in angular or is there any alternative?

Comment: `fs` and `path` are core Node modules, they're not available in the browser where an Angular app is running. What are you trying to _achieve_ by using it - it seems to be for parsing INI files, where will those be coming from?

Comment: I m trying to use this package for parsing .properties file. The files will be coming from API call.